# Jerky/laggy scrolling

Tags: 11.10, compiz, nvidia

I run 11.10 with unity, NVidia Quadro NVS 140M with driver 280.13.

In a fresh session, graphics performance is ok. However, after a while or with some open applications, 2D-scrolling performance degrades heavily. Scrolling through a 800-line text file takes half a minute, with frequent freezes in the process, rendering any text editing mostly unusable for me.

Interestingly, I can run two full screen HD videos with both the videos and text scrolling in Geany seemingly unaffected. On the other hand, as soon as I open any another application that involves 2D-scrolling (browser, terminal, text editor,...), it gets all incredibly jerky and laggy - only the scrolling, general performance is still acceptable.

In unity-2D, things are ok so I guess the culprit may be Compiz. Is this a bug or just expected on a not-high-end graphics card? I don't expect silky-smoothness here but, seriously, no usable text-scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

I get the same issue. If you use NVidia drivers, there are issues with performance when using the NVidia graphics card. Try: sudo apt-add-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates &&
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get remove nvidia-current PLUS: I found a bit of an improvement increasing the composite refresh rate found in the Compiz-Setting-Manger PLUS: there are issues with Compiz and Unity, despite what some say, it is unstable and easily broken..